# unable to link my SO profile from Careers

Tags: support

This apparently looks like a bug, but I don't have a tracker link for that.
When I edit my profile on careers, I have no stack exchange network sites listed when I hit edit under the stack exchange section. And trying to add my answers manually is also ignored AFAICS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be all set now.  You had two accounts because we had previously automatically created one for you based on your SO profile.  It looks like they were automatically merged about 10 minutes after you posted here.