# Unable to link SE accounts from Careers profile, still an ongoing bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Similar to:

[Unable to link SE accounts from Careers profile (but can link to SO answers)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129492/unable-to-link-se-accounts-from-careers-profile-but-can-link-to-so-answers)

[Unable to link SE accounts on Stack Careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133686/unable-to-link-se-accounts-on-stack-careers)

[unable to link my SO profile from Careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90174/unable-to-link-my-so-profile-from-careers)

[My Careers 2.0 account is not linked to my Stack Overflow account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125286/my-careers-2-0-account-is-not-linked-to-my-stack-overflow-account/125296#125296)

I am unable to link to my SE accounts, although yesterday I was able to. I have followed all suggestions on the answers to no avail. It seems that this is still an ongoing bug.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: @rekire I don't see anything wrong with your account.  Can you please give more information about what appears to be wrong?

Comment: @NickLarsen now that works. Yesterday was that list empty. Sorry for this wrong alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated your account to attach correctly.

We are unable to determine exactly why this is happening just yet, and we are unable to reproduce it.  We are going to add some features this week to make this situation easier to deal with by allowing users to sync their accounts manually.

In the meantime, anyone who experiences this problem, please post a message in the comments here and I will update your account.  We don't need to create a new post for each one of these.

Comment: If it helps, the only thing that I did yesterday was remove the picture I had linked from my gravatar account and reset my password for said gravatar account. Thanks for the quick response NickLarsen!

Comment: @Hooked making those changes on the gravatar site won't affect us.  If you are turning off your gravatar on your profile (the checkbox to not show it), I was unable to repro the result with any type of user.  Thanks for the info though, I bet it's something out of the way like that.